# Listing All Classes And Instances from N-triple file with Jena

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, knowledge-graph, n-triples

I am a beginner and want to list all the entities/classes and instance from N-triple file through Jena but I don't know how to do it. Or it is possible to do this with Sparql.

I have already load the N-triple file as a JENA model.

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
RDFDataMgr.read(model, "F:\\dbtune_org_magnatune_sparqlCut1.nt", Lang.NTRIPLES);
```

Here is the link of N-triple file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/143PJ8_fgJdyNbB8sjvErpdP371uO6glv/view

Comment: use the Jena documentation, maybe even the ontology API (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) - I don't know if your data is OWL or just plain RDF

Comment: It's plain RDF file.

Comment: The file has many warnings - URIs with `<....Violin%2B%2>` -- the %2 at the end is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what is being asked here, but the starting point could be a simple SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?instance ?class {
  ?instance a ?class
}
```

which gives you all the "instances" (anything that is in a `rdf:type` relation with anything) and corresponding classes. Or you could do

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?class {
  ?instance a ?class
}
```

which gives you everything that is used as a class. And so on...

Comment: He's asking for a solution pertaining to Jena API not SPARQL query.